# Courier imap ssl doesn't start at reboot

Tags: courier-imap

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12.06 to 16.06.

I have an otherwise working Courier IMAP setup with a non-SSL and SSL config. When I reboot, the non-SSL version starts, and the SSL version does not.

I've done a "systemctl enable courier-imap-ssl"

When I reboot it seems to start:

```
Sep 11 16:14:32 x systemd[1]: Starting Courier Authentification Daemon...
Sep 11 16:14:32 x systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Courier IMAP server...
Sep 11 16:14:32 x systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Courier IMAP-SSL server...
Sep 11 16:14:32 x systemd[1]: Starting LSB: saslauthd startup script...
Sep 11 16:14:32 x systemd[1]: Started Courier Authentification Daemon.
Sep 11 16:14:32 x courier-imap-ssl[3570]:  * Starting Courier IMAP-SSL server imapd-ssl
Sep 11 16:14:33 x courier-imap-ssl[3570]:    ...done.
Sep 11 16:14:33 x systemd[1]: Started LSB: Courier IMAP-SSL server.
Sep 11 16:14:33 x courier-imap[3569]:  * Starting Courier IMAP server imapd
Sep 11 16:14:33 x courier-imap[3569]:    ...done.
Sep 11 16:14:33 x systemd[1]: Started LSB: Courier IMAP server.
Sep 11 16:14:33 x systemd[1]: Started LSB: saslauthd startup script.
```

However when I login shortly after the ssl version's couriertcpd doesn't show up as a process.

If I then "service start courier-imap-ssl" it starts fine and stays up.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

$ systemctl status courier-imap-ssl

imapd-ssl[#]: bind: Cannot assign requested address

The startup scripts provided out-of-the-box are missing the $network dependency.